# unexpected token: com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0

Tags: android, github, implementation, exoplayer

I am not able to add the GitHub repository of Youtube video extractor for exoplayer, implementing in android studio project.

build.gridle(abc app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gridle(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
          //  multiDexEnabled true
            //useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc03"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.4.4'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Adding exoplayer dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'

    //Youtube extractor
    Implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0' // getting error in this line 


}
```

When I'm trying to add the "Implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'", I don't know why showing the below error -

```
unexpected token: com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0

Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Rupesh\AndroidStudioProjects\abc\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\Rupesh\AndroidStudioProjects\abc\app\build.gradle': 84: unexpected token: com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0 @ line 84, column 20.
     Implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does case matter in gradle task method names?](/q/35328120/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Use **i** instead of **I** in `implementation`.

The correct line should be
`implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'`